# Plot a function with a recursion relation

Tags: recursion

Consider the following functions:

```
r[x_] := r0 Exp[(k x)/(r1/(r1 + r[x]))];
f[x_] := (k x)/(r1/(r1 + r[x]));
```

and that

```
r1=1; r0=1; k=1;
```

I'd like to plot the function `f[x]`:

```
Plot[(k x)/(r1/(r1 + r[x])),{x,-1,1}]
```

How can the recursion relation can be dealt with?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For recursion relations we can use `RSolve` (this case can be solved algebraically however, see comments):

```
sol1 = RSolve[r[x] == r0 Exp[(k x)/(r1/(r1 + r[x]))], r[x], x]
```

to plot:

```
Plot[(k x)/(r1/(r1 + r[x])) /. sol1 /. {r1 -> 1, r0 -> 1, 
   k -> 1}, {x, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: You will however have this warning: `Solve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information.`

Comment: And in this specific case, there is no need for recursion so `sol2 = Solve[r[x] == r0 Exp[(k x)/(r1/(r1 + r[x]))], r[x]]` will give you the exact same thing algebraically